# Is there a way to bind multiple key combinations to spyder shortcuts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder, shortcut

I'm used to being able to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run the selected line.
Is there a way to bind both of these combinations?

[image]

Each of these categories only accepts one key binding as far as I am aware.

Thanks is advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to add multiple key binds for a single shortcut inside Spyder as far as I know. This has been brought up before and I believe they are working on it for a future update. Their plans for further keyboard shortcut support in Spyder can be found here: [checklist](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/7894)

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Just to add a bit to your answer: we have plans to add multiple shortcuts in Spyder 5, to be released at the end of 2020.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba is there an update to when this feature will be implemented? I'm not seeing it in Spyder 5.

Comment: @Nathaniel, unfortunately we haven't had time to implement this, sorry.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba thanks for the response. Spyder is awesome, and I look forward to the many improvements in store.